# Not showing Project Folder Structure in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an open source project.

After I have opened it, I did not find the project folders and files, which are on the left side of the screen:

[image]

What do I do to show the Project Folder Structure?

Comment: I think you can find on window tab.

Comment: have u try `Alt+1` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android Studio creates the necessary structure for all your files and makes them visible in the Project window on the left side of the IDE (click **View > Tool Windows > Project**). This page provides an overview of the key components inside your project.

Answer (score 5):

Go to **View => Tool Windows => Project.**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go To File >> Invalidate Caches/Restart.. Then your android studio restart and automatically it show this project structure try this it really help me to solve this same issue..

Comment: Solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

> View -> Apprearance -> Tool Windows Bars

Helped me to bring back the project panel, resource manager, Buildvariants, favorite, structure **at the left side of the window** and TODO, Version Control, Logcat, Build, Terminal **at the bottom of the window**.

I don't know how it got disappeared, maybe pressing the keys by mistake. But this helped me out.

**Android Studio Version:** 
Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to collapse/uncollapse the project files structure.